# Google charts more decimals

Tags: database, google-visualization, linechart

I would like to show more decimals in my google line chart. At the moment the chart doesn't show the numbers after the decimal point. I would like for the chart to show 2 or 3 decimals.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "Lat.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 600, height: 400});
}


</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--Div that will hold the chart-->
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The chart shows data from a database, I call upon this data with this code :

```
<?php

$databaseName = "pws";
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'usbw') or die('Error connecting to server');
mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con); 
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM gpx');

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

   array('label' => 'id',  'type' => 'number'),
   array('label' => 'Lat', 'type' => 'number'),
   array('label' => 'Lon', 'type' => 'number'),
   array('label' => 'Ele', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

$temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int)$r['id']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Lat']); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Lon']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Ele']);

$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}


$table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

Does anybody know how I can make the line chart show more decimals?

Edit:
Nevermind, I managed to solve it.
The (int)'s in the php file were the problem, by removing them the problem was solved

Comment: Not able to understand your problem, Line chart renders based on the data you have provided. In case you have decimals in data you need to make sure PHP script formats it correctly to have two decimal points and the chart library will render it appropriately.

I would advise to modify Google chart JSFiddle with your structure and sample data to test whether you are able to achieve what you require without testing it in your environment. If possible create your own fiddle and share it to describe the problem in more detail.

http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: I managed to find the problem, I simply had to remove the (int)'s in the php file. Now it works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to see that, I was having doubt that in your PHP code it might be stripping the decimals. Please update your question or provide an answer and accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the (int)'s in the php file I managed to make it work

Like this :

```
$temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['id']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Lat']); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Lon']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Ele']);

$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
```